# How do I make a combobox show a tab control like VS' when setting a color?

Tags: winapi, custom-controls, tabcontrol, groupbox

I mean this control:

[image]

When you click on this, instead of regular options, a tab control with the colors is displayed. How can I do this? is this a owner-draw combobox or something else? I'm aware on how draw text, rectangles, images, etc with a owner-draw combobox but I don't know how add controls over there. I have no code to show yet because I have no idea how do that. I've tried something like call `CreateWindow()` in `WM_DRAWITEM` using the values from `DRAWITEMSTRUCT.rcItem` but I can't make a control inside the groupbox's client area, the button gets behind the control.

Comment: Do you mean [Color Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/color-dialog-box)?  Of course, you can [Customizing the Color Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/color-dialog-box#customizing-the-color-dialog-box)

Comment: No, I mean show that color dialog box instead of the combobox's items when you click in that Combobox(I guess it's one)

Comment: Don't know what you're looking at, but this is probably .NET's ColorEditor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.coloreditor source is here https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/src/System.Windows.Forms.Design/src/System/Drawing/Design/ColorEditor.cs using regular .NET TabControl.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for [CBN_DROPDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cbn-dropdown).

> Sent when the list box of a combo box is about to be made visible. The
> parent window of the combo box receives this notification code through
> the WM_COMMAND message.

Some code:

```
HWND hWndComboBox = CreateWindow(
       WC_COMBOBOX,
       TEXT(""),
       WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST,
       10, 20, 70, 17,
       hWnd, (HMENU)IDB_COMBOX, hInstance, NULL);

...
 case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {         
            case IDB_COMBOX:
            {
                switch (HIWORD(wParam))
                {
                case CBN_DROPDOWN:
                {
                    CHOOSECOLOR cc;                 // common dialog box structure 
                    static COLORREF acrCustClr[16]; // array of custom colors                
                    static DWORD rgbCurrent;        // initial color selection

                    // Initialize CHOOSECOLOR 
                    ZeroMemory(&cc, sizeof(cc));
                    cc.lStructSize = sizeof(cc);
                    cc.hwndOwner = hWnd;
                    cc.lpCustColors = (LPDWORD)acrCustClr;
                    cc.rgbResult = rgbCurrent;
                    cc.Flags = CC_FULLOPEN | CC_RGBINIT;
                    ChooseColor(&cc);
            
                }
                    break;
                ...
```

Debug:

[image: 1]

Comment: Not exactly that, the color box there seems to be a tab control, with the tabs "Personalizar", "Web", "Sistema". Can I show that cotrol, that seems to be a  tab control, from `CBN_DROPDOWN`?

Comment: @Jack I think the answer is yes. Please read [About Tab Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tab-controls) and [Add Controls To Specific Tab Page in TabControl in C++ Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164272/add-controls-to-specific-tab-page-in-tabcontrol-in-c-win32). Call tab control under the `CBN_DROPDOWN` event.

Comment: I'm aware of `CBN_DROPDOWN` event but I couldn't make a tab control show up below a combobox's area. It seems you can't make a control to be down on top of another, since windows vista so I asked this question here on SO

Comment: @Jack I haven't tried anything like this. If you need it, I will test it in a while and update it here.

Comment: I would be thankful, I haven't made it work yet.