# How to make scroll inside WC_TABCONTROL? - Winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a tabcontrol with a lot of content and want to add a scroll bar so you can scroll down and see all the content.

I made WC_TABCONTROL control and set there WS_VSCROLL. The scroll line shows up but it does not work and the content of the box is cut off.

I am looking for some easy way to make the scroll work, not just show up.

Comment: Put your content on a child dialog, and put the scroll bar on that rather than on the tab. Also it's better to make your content pages siblings of the tab control, not children (see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211110-00/?p=105889 for why).

Comment: Thank you, that helped

Comment: That is even mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tab-controls): "*The display area of a tab control is the area in which an application displays the current page. Typically, an application creates a child window or dialog box, setting the window size and position to fit the display area... More often, each page consists of a child window or dialog box. In this case, an application might process [TCN_SELCHANGE] by destroying or hiding the outgoing child window or dialog box and by creating or showing the incoming child window or dialog box.*"

Answer (score 1):

As @Jonathan Potter and the linked blog said, I combined [@Barmak Shemirani answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34219117/15511041) with [How to Scroll Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/scroll-text-in-scroll-bars) to get the following code.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include "resource.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

HINSTANCE g_hinst;

struct TData {
    HWND page1, page2, page3;
    HWND tab;
} data;

BOOL CALLBACK DialogPage(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    TEXTMETRIC tm;
    SCROLLINFO si;

    // These variables are required to display text. 
    static int xClient;     // width of client area 
    static int yClient;     // height of client area 
    static int xClientMax;  // maximum width of client area 

    static int xChar;       // horizontal scrolling unit 
    static int yChar;       // vertical scrolling unit 
    static int xUpper;      // average width of uppercase letters 

    static int xPos;        // current horizontal scrolling position 
    static int yPos;        // current vertical scrolling position 

    int i;                  // loop counter 
    int x, y;               // horizontal and vertical coordinates

    int FirstLine;          // first line in the invalidated area 
    int LastLine;           // last line in the invalidated area 
    HRESULT hr;
    size_t abcLength;        // length of an abc[] item 

    // Create an array of lines to display. 
#define LINES 28 
    static const TCHAR* abc[] = {
           TEXT("anteater"),  TEXT("bear"),      TEXT("cougar"),
           TEXT("dingo"),     TEXT("elephant"),  TEXT("falcon"),
           TEXT("gazelle"),   TEXT("hyena"),     TEXT("iguana"),
           TEXT("jackal"),    TEXT("kangaroo"),  TEXT("llama"),
           TEXT("moose"),     TEXT("newt"),      TEXT("octopus"),
           TEXT("penguin"),   TEXT("quail"),     TEXT("rat"),
           TEXT("squid"),     TEXT("tortoise"),  TEXT("urus"),
           TEXT("vole"),      TEXT("walrus"),    TEXT("xylophone"),
           TEXT("yak"),       TEXT("zebra"),
           TEXT("This line contains words, but no character. Go figure."),
           TEXT("")
    };

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        // Get the handle to the client area's device context. 
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

        // Extract font dimensions from the text metrics. 
        GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
        xChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
        xUpper = (tm.tmPitchAndFamily & 1 ? 3 : 2) * xChar / 2;
        yChar = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;

        // Free the device context. 
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

        // Set an arbitrary maximum width for client area. 
        // (xClientMax is the sum of the widths of 48 average 
        // lowercase letters and 12 uppercase letters.) 
        xClientMax = 48 * xChar + 12 * xUpper;

        return TRUE;

    case WM_SIZE:

        // Retrieve the dimensions of the client area. 
        yClient = HIWORD(lParam);
        xClient = LOWORD(lParam);

        // Set the vertical scrolling range and page size
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE;
        si.nMin = 0;
        si.nMax = LINES - 1;
        si.nPage = yClient / yChar;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);

        // Set the horizontal scrolling range and page size. 
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE;
        si.nMin = 0;
        si.nMax = 2 + xClientMax / xChar;
        si.nPage = xClient / xChar;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE);

        return 0;
    case WM_HSCROLL:
        // Get all the vertial scroll bar information.
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_ALL;

        // Save the position for comparison later on.
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si);
        xPos = si.nPos;
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            // User clicked the left arrow.
        case SB_LINELEFT:
            si.nPos -= 1;
            break;

            // User clicked the right arrow.
        case SB_LINERIGHT:
            si.nPos += 1;
            break;

            // User clicked the scroll bar shaft left of the scroll box.
        case SB_PAGELEFT:
            si.nPos -= si.nPage;
            break;

            // User clicked the scroll bar shaft right of the scroll box.
        case SB_PAGERIGHT:
            si.nPos += si.nPage;
            break;

            // User dragged the scroll box.
        case SB_THUMBTRACK:
            si.nPos = si.nTrackPos;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        // Set the position and then retrieve it.  Due to adjustments
        // by Windows it may not be the same as the value set.
        si.fMask = SIF_POS;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE);
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si);

        // If the position has changed, scroll the window.
        if (si.nPos != xPos)
        {
            ScrollWindow(hwnd, xChar * (xPos - si.nPos), 0, NULL, NULL);
        }

        return 0;

    case WM_VSCROLL:
        // Get all the vertial scroll bar information.
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_ALL;
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);

        // Save the position for comparison later on.
        yPos = si.nPos;
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {

            // User clicked the HOME keyboard key.
        case SB_TOP:
            si.nPos = si.nMin;
            break;

            // User clicked the END keyboard key.
        case SB_BOTTOM:
            si.nPos = si.nMax;
            break;

            // User clicked the top arrow.
        case SB_LINEUP:
            si.nPos -= 1;
            break;

            // User clicked the bottom arrow.
        case SB_LINEDOWN:
            si.nPos += 1;
            break;

            // User clicked the scroll bar shaft above the scroll box.
        case SB_PAGEUP:
            si.nPos -= si.nPage;
            break;

            // User clicked the scroll bar shaft below the scroll box.
        case SB_PAGEDOWN:
            si.nPos += si.nPage;
            break;

            // User dragged the scroll box.
        case SB_THUMBTRACK:
            si.nPos = si.nTrackPos;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        // Set the position and then retrieve it.  Due to adjustments
        // by Windows it may not be the same as the value set.
        si.fMask = SIF_POS;
        SetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);

        // If the position has changed, scroll window and update it.
        if (si.nPos != yPos)
        {
            ScrollWindow(hwnd, 0, yChar * (yPos - si.nPos), NULL, NULL);
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        }

        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        // Prepare the window for painting.
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        // Get vertical scroll bar position.
        si.cbSize = sizeof(si);
        si.fMask = SIF_POS;
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_VERT, &si);
        yPos = si.nPos;

        // Get horizontal scroll bar position.
        GetScrollInfo(hwnd, SB_HORZ, &si);
        xPos = si.nPos;

        // Find painting limits.
        FirstLine = max(0, yPos + ps.rcPaint.top / yChar);
        LastLine = min(LINES - 1, yPos + ps.rcPaint.bottom / yChar);

        for (i = FirstLine; i <= LastLine; i++)
        {
            x = xChar * (1 - xPos);
            y = yChar * (i - yPos);

            // Note that "55" in the following depends on the 
            // maximum size of an abc[] item. Also, you must include
            // strsafe.h to use the StringCchLength function.
            hr = StringCchLength(abc[i], 55, &abcLength);
            if ((FAILED(hr)) | (abcLength == NULL))
            {
                //
                // TODO: write error handler
                //
            }

            // Write a line of text to the client area.
            TextOut(hdc, x, y, abc[i], abcLength);
        }

        // Indicate that painting is finished.
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

void OnSelChange() {
    int sel = TabCtrl_GetCurSel(data.tab);
    ShowWindow(data.page1, (sel == 0) ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);
    ShowWindow(data.page2, (sel == 1) ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);
}

BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp)
{
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG: {
        data.page1 = CreateDialog(g_hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG2), hwnd, DialogPage);
        data.page2 = CreateDialog(g_hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG3), hwnd, DialogPage);

        data.tab = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_TAB1);
        if (data.tab)
        {
            TCITEM tci = { 0 };
            tci.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
            tci.pszText = (PTCHAR)L"Page1";
            TabCtrl_InsertItem(data.tab, 0, &tci);
            tci.pszText = (PTCHAR)L"Page2";
            TabCtrl_InsertItem(data.tab, 1, &tci);

            RECT rc;//find tab control's rectangle
            GetWindowRect(data.tab, &rc);
            POINT offset = { 0 };
            ScreenToClient(hwnd, &offset);
            OffsetRect(&rc, offset.x, offset.y); //convert to client coordinates
            rc.top += 50;
            SetWindowPos(data.page1, 0, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, SWP_HIDEWINDOW);
            SetWindowPos(data.page2, 0, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, SWP_HIDEWINDOW);

            OnSelChange();
        }

        break;
    }

    case WM_NOTIFY: {
        switch (((LPNMHDR)lp)->code) {
        case TCN_SELCHANGE:
            OnSelChange();
            break;
        }
    }
                  break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        EndDialog(hwnd, wp);
        EndDialog(data.page1, wp);
        EndDialog(data.page2, wp);
        break;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int)
{
    g_hinst = hinst;
    DialogBox(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, DialogProc);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]